# Keyboard layout and displayed characters

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout, character-encoding, charset

What does happen when one switch keyboard layout (alt+shift in Windows) for e.g. from `en` to `pl`. Does it change the charset from english to polish or maybe encoding? Why when for e.g. setting it to `en` gives an `ø` character while setting it to `pl` gives `ł`?

Answer (score 0):

Switching keyboard layout (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> in Windows) leads to switching between [keyboard functional layouts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Functional_layouts).

A particular [keyboard](http://ascii-table.com/keyboards.php) functional layout provides **mapping between [scancodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scancode)** from a physical key (or a key combination) **and some software events**, e.g.

- <kbd>e</kbd>: the letter “e” appears on the screen;
- <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>: the letter “E” appears on the screen;
- <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>: circulates through installed keyboard layouts/languages/input methods;
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> launches Windows Task manager;
- etc.

Another example:

- <kbd>AltGR</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>

  - gives the `€` *Euro Sign* on a [Czech keyboard layout (243)](http://ascii-table.com/keyboard.php/243), but
  - gives the `ę` *Latin Letter E With Ogonek* on a [Polish keyboard layout (457)](http://ascii-table.com/keyboard.php/457), while
- <kbd>AltGR</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>

  - gives nothing  on a [Czech keyboard layout (243)](http://ascii-table.com/keyboard.php/243), but
  - gives the `€` *Euro Sign* on both [Polish keyboard layout (457)](http://ascii-table.com/keyboard.php/457) and [Polish keyboard layout (214)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/globalization/keyboards/kbdpl.html).